# How to extract terrain heightmap from some free online map (OpenStreetMap,GoogleMaps, NASA WinWorld etc.)

Tags: heightmap

I downloaded some small tile ( 10x10km ) from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) but I don't see what is the simplest way how to get actuall heightmap [like this](https://forums.unrealengine.com/filedata/fetch?id=1167773&d=1449006880) out of `.osm` file.

I'm looking to [Python OSM API](https://github.com/metaodi/osmapi)  but I don't see anything about height/altitude channel. Also OpenStreetMap wiki-page about [relief](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relief_maps) and [altitude](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Altitude) is not very helpful.

In these two projects 
[pyvotons](http://www.pyvotons.org/?page_id=183) and 
[Shadow Mapper](https://github.com/perliedman/shadow-mapper)
they seem to do it somehow, but I hesitate to dig into 
their code, if there is simpler answer.

Comment: OpenStreetMap's page on altitude says "Height (elevation) is still rarely stored in the database." so it might not be a good source for this data. For instance, the pyvotons example you link says they got their terrain elevation data from [another source](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp). Can you tell us a bit more about what areas/features you need height data for? You also might want to ask mapping & GIS experts for advice on procuring this data. As game developers we can help you get the data into your game, but we're not necessarily experts on where to source it from.

Comment: Great! thanks I overlooked that SRTM. That is exactly what I searched for.

Comment: I wanted to make some realistic tactical game with tanks from wwII, and just for fun I want to use map area around town where I'm born since I know it.

Comment: I expect generation of Terrain Height map is a very common task in game-development, so I was hoping somebody already tried to grab those height maps from some online map.

Comment: *Generation* of height maps is a common task in game development - but often we're generating maps of fictional places, or stylizing / TARDIS-ing real places into fictional versions. ;) Did the link from pyvotons get you what you need?

Comment: lot of games are from real world history etc. Yes I got what I wanted... I just downloaded 12000x12000 pixel height map of Czech Republic. Now I have to think what exactly I want to do with it.